# Is it possible to create a Context Menu item in Windows 10 like a Checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, windows-10, registry, contextmenu, microsoft-file-explorer

More specifically, I want to right-click on an image file and then click a Context Menu Item that will enable a certain property of that file. I'm designing a wallpaper changer program and the images I enabled on the Context Menu will be accepted by the program as a valid image to be used, otherwise, the program won't use the image.

A good example of what I want would be the "Lock all taskbars" when you right-click the Taskbar. To uncheck it allows you to move the Taskbar however you want it on your display.

I'm sure this involves creating a new item in the Context Menu within the registry, but is there any way I can have this checkbox function when right-clicking a file?